# Save method won't update models that already exist in the DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I retrieve properly the records in my DB and print out the values in textfield. But when I want to update my database it won't work. It says in the documentation that

> `save()` method may also be used to update models that already exist
>   in the database. To update a model, you should retrieve it.

So I have two blade template **show** and **edit**. First blade show the value exist in the database (GET REQUEST). Second blade show the edit form for the user to update data. (POST REQUEST).

show.blade.php

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.show', $result->id) }}">

<h3>View Employee</h3>
<hr>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" placeholder = "{{ $result->email }}" readonly>

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "{{ $result->username }}" readonly>

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form class = "form-vertical" role = "form" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('account.edit', $result->id) }}">

<h3>Edit Employee</h3>
<hr>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "email" class = "control-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "email" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->email }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <label for = "username" class = "control-label">Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username" class = "form-control" value = "{{ $result->username }}">

</div>

<div class = "form-group">

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Save</button>

</div>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
//SHOW
public function showEmployee($id)
{
    $result = User::find($id);

                                        //key     //value
    return view ('account.show')->with('result', $result);
}

//EDIT
public function editEmployee($id)
{

    $result = User::find($id);

    return view ('account.edit')->with('result', $result);
}

//UPDATE
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
                            //This will be unique in users table
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$id.'|email|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,'.$id.'|alpha|max:20',
    ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $username = $request['username'];

    $user = User::findOrFail($id); 
    $user->email = $email; //Accessing properties of Model
    $user->username = $username;

    $user->save();

    return view ('account.show');
}
```

Routes:

```
//SHOW
Route::get('/show/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@showEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.show',
]);

//EDIT
Route::get('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@editEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);


//UPDATE
Route::post('/edit/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@updateEmployee',
    'as' => 'account.edit',
]);
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on laravel, but I think the problem is due to you're creating a new user, filling the name and then trying to save it, so laravel thinks that you are trying to save a duplicated object...You should verify if the object already exist first...if it exists, fetch it and then modify the fields and save it, else just create a new one and save it.

Comment: I just followed the documentation it says I can update using the same method which is save() but before that I should retrieve the value first.

Comment: Yes, you should, because by fetching it, you are fetching the User id and the another fields that are already saved, and then you can do the modifications based on the updated object (an object which represents the real state of the database). But...remember that I don't have experience on laravel, I just trying give you the Sunday help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `User` here.

To update the existing data, you need to first load the user data you want to edit. You can do this and fix that problem by changing

```
$user = new User();
```

to

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

(Assuming `$id` is the id of that user here)

Moreover, your validation will fail here if both the username and email are not changed since you're checking for the uniqueness of both entries and the current user will already have that username or email.

To fix this, you need to exclude the current user from the check through something like this for the validation,

```
  'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$id.'|email|max:255',
  'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,'.$id.'|alpha|max:20',
```

For more information, see 'Forcing a unique rule to ignore a given id' in the documentation here - [Validation - unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: I didn't expect that it can concatenate the `$id` in validation. Last question. When I hit the button it gives me a error `Undefined variable: result (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\account\show.blade.php)` but it's updating in my DB. I updated my post. Appreciated your time!

Comment: You're not loading `result` with the view from `updateEmployee` However, I would recommend simply redirecting to the `account.show` route instead of returning a view from updateEmployee.

Comment: @Francisunoxx You can do that using `return redirect()->route('account.show');`

Comment: My bad for that didn't notice I was returning the view. When I hit the button it says `Missing required parameters for [Route: account.show] [URI: show/{id}]`

Comment: Yes it's updating in the database even I got this error after hitting the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updateEmployee` method is not using the provided `$id` parameter, and you just create a new User instance and save it, instead you need to retrieve the existing model and update it:

```
$user = User::find($id);// retrieve the existing user
$user->email = $email;
$user->username = $username;

$user->save();// update the record in DB
```